# How do i solve the "doesn't match anything issue" when submitting a bug with mylyn to bugzilla with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, bug-tracking, bugzilla, mylyn

I'm trying to submit a bug to a bugzilla server with mylyn task plugin in eclipse, but when i sent it server replies : **Assignee:<name> did not match anything** being name the the user from my mail sent, seem to be splitting my email from the @.

Actually i'm using Mylyn 3.4.1 and eclipse 3.5.2, does anyone had this issue before or knows how to solve it?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this like in [bug 167949](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=167949#c11)?

> On the bugzilla repository settings page for this repository, ensure that "`Local users enabled`" isn't check.
>   When selected, the "`@...`" is trimmed from the field upon submit.

Related to [bug 166555](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=166555):

> There is now a "Local users enabled:" check box on the Bugzilla repository settings page.
>   Enable this and only the username will be sent in the QA field rather then the entire address.

Comment: just a second ago seen that parameter in the authentication settings in a work partner's computer, so that's the right answer, just worked ok, thanks :)